# mysterious include of comdef.h

Tags: c++, macros, include-path

In my project there are some compilation error `C2872` due to ambiguous definition of `byte`, after I set [`-Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk.aspx), the output shows that `C2872` is due to the in included file:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\comdef.h

from one of my `myado.h` file.

However, this is no such include anywhere in `myado.h`, how come it is included?

`myado.h` did something like this:

```
#import "C:/Program Files/Common Files/System/ado/msado15.dll"  rename("EOF", "adoEOF") rename("BOF", "adoBOF")

#include <icrsint.h>  // ADO C/C++ Record Binding Definitions

#define TESTHR(x) if FAILED(x) _com_issue_error(x)
```

, here `FAILED` is a macro defined in

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\shared\winerror.h

and `_com_issue_error` is defined in

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\comutil.h

is this the reason?

But if this is the case, how were the header files got included, due to the marco usage?

Or, how was c++ compiler visual studio recognize the macro definition?

Comment: Show the actual code from `myado.h`, not *something like* the code. *Why does this code behave this way?* can't be answered if we don't get to see the actual code. (The import statement is importing a type library (TLB) from the DLL, and that TLB is for ADO, which are based on ActiveX, which is based on COM, which is what _com* references, and the definitions for COM come from comdef.h.)

Comment: @KenWhite that's not necessary -- put in simple, my code used com related things but never **directly** include `comutil.h`, however, visual studio compilation output says so, so how come `comutil.h` got into the party without invitation?

Comment: From the TLB that's imported. I thought I explained that above.

Comment: @KenWhite but the code only imports the `msado5.dll` from C:/Program Files/Common Files/System/ado/, there's no importing or including of a `.tlb` file, nor could I find a `msado15.tlb` on hard disk -- there are some `msado20/21/25/26/27/28/60.tlb` in the `System` folder though.

Comment: The TLB is embedded in the DLL. It's imported from that DLL by (strangely enough) the `#import` statement. What did you think the purpose of the `#import` was?

Comment: @KenWhite now i see the picture, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all credit goes to Ken White.

After compilation, due to `#import "C:/Program Files/Common Files/System/ado/msado15.dll"  rename("EOF", "adoEOF") rename("BOF", "adoBOF")`

, a `msado15.tlh` will be generated under project's `Debug` folder, which starts as:

```
// Created by Microsoft (R) C/C++ Compiler Version 14.12.25830.2 (dbe79e7e).
//
// c:\c20180411hp_cpp17_01\debug\msado15.tlh
//
// C++ source equivalent of type library C:/Program Files/Common Files/System/ado/msado15.dll
// compiler-generated file created 06/20/18 at 15:50:36 - DO NOT EDIT!

#pragma once
#pragma pack(push, 8)

#include <comdef.h>
```

, voila!